# Why multithreading and multiprocessing is slower than doing nothing when using LOAD DATA INFILE to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, csv, multiprocessing

I need to load a file with 2 million rows in csv format to a mysql database as fast as posible.

The process is the following:
I have a 2 million rows file.
I split it into two 1 million rows file.
Then I use python threading/multiprocessing/concurrent.futures module to execute the LOAD DATA INFILE on each file.

The problem is that the whole 2 million rows file takes 60 seconds to be written to mysql but when I use threading or multiprocessing it takes 90 seconds.

This is the code I'm using:

```
from concurrent.futures import thread
import mysql.connector
import time
from threading import Thread
import multiprocessing

def write_large(path):
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='python',
            password='rvlPBO67.',
            database='test'
        )
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    sql=f"LOAD DATA INFILE '{path}' INTO TABLE cereal FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 ROWS;"
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    mydb.commit()
   
def main():

    t1= time.perf_counter()

    write_1=multiprocessing.Process(target=write_large,args=['/var/lib/mysql-files/cerealLong1.csv'])
    write_2=multiprocessing.Process(target=write_large,args=['/var/lib/mysql-files/cerealLong2.csv'])

    write_1.start()
    write_2.start()
    write_1.join()
    write_2.join()

    t2=time.perfcounter()
    print(f'finished in {t2-t1} seconds')
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You have violated the rule that all one-time only code must be in an `if __name__=="__main__":` block.  Beyond that, Python is not the bottleneck in this code, so multithreading/multiprocessing is unlikely to help, and you're adding contention.  There isn't any way to load data faster than `LOAD DATA`.  You have a 60-second job here.

Comment: I understand that 60 seconds is already very fast but I was wondering why if I use multiprocessing the time doesn't go lower than that if supposedly  I´m doing it in parallel. By the way I am just testing this thing thats why I didn't use the if __name__ but I'll implement that for sure haha...Is it posible that the bottleneck is related to mysql?is it physically imposible to use multiprocessing then?

Comment: how do the big companies deal with hundreds of millions of rows then?

Comment: I've worked in an environment with petabyte-scale data across thousands of servers. I've seen it take hours or days to import hundreds of millions of rows on a busy server. We can speed it up a little by getting a more powerful and expensive server (Xeon processor, 200GB RAM, NVMe storage in RAID configuration, etc.). But you have to expect it takes a long time to import data when the scale  is thousands of times larger than it is on a beginner-level project.

Comment: They set reasonable expectations.  We get spoiled because computers are so fast, but they are not infinitely fast.  Importing gigabytes takes time.

Comment: Think of the bottlenecks in the multithreaded situation:  1 I/O subsystem doing 2 reads and two writes.  1 database server coordinating writes to a single table.  The OS coordinating things.  Etc.  Also, depending on the indexes, there could be additional contention there.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we may have some tips to help.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Additional OS information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.